# Error while using sparse model matrix

Tags: r, shiny, xgboost

Hi I am programming here in R, and I want to use the `xgboost` function for predicting a dummy variable.

That's the code:

```
library(xgboost)

library(Matrix)

mydata<-read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE,sep=",")

names(mydata)

 [1] "Factor_Check"                  "Cor_Check"                     "Cor_Check4"                   
 [4] "Cor_Check2"                    "n_tokens_title"                "n_tokens_content"             
 [7] "n_unique_tokens"               "n_non_stop_words"              "n_non_stop_unique_tokens"     
[10] "num_hrefs"                     "num_self_hrefs"                "num_imgs"                     
[13] "num_videos"                    "average_token_length"          "num_keywords"                 
[16] "data_channel_is_lifestyle"     "data_channel_is_entertainment" "data_channel_is_bus"          
[19] "data_channel_is_socmed"        "data_channel_is_tech"          "data_channel_is_world"        
[22] "kw_min_min"                    "kw_max_min"                    "kw_avg_min"                   
[25] "kw_min_max"                    "kw_max_max"                    "kw_avg_max"                   
[28] "kw_min_avg"                    "kw_max_avg"                    "kw_avg_avg"                   
[31] "self_reference_min_shares"     "self_reference_max_shares"     "self_reference_avg_sharess"   
[34] "weekday_is_monday"             "weekday_is_tuesday"            "weekday_is_wednesday"         
[37] "weekday_is_thursday"           "weekday_is_friday"             "weekday_is_saturday"          
[40] "weekday_is_sunday"             "is_weekend"                    "LDA_00"                       
[43] "LDA_01"                        "LDA_02"                        "LDA_03"                       
[46] "LDA_04"                        "global_subjectivity"           "global_sentiment_polarity"    
[49] "global_rate_positive_words"    "global_rate_negative_words"    "rate_positive_words"          
[52] "rate_negative_words"           "avg_positive_polarity"         "min_positive_polarity"        
[55] "max_positive_polarity"         "avg_negative_polarity"         "min_negative_polarity"        
[58] "max_negative_polarity"         "title_subjectivity"            "title_sentiment_polarity"     
[61] "abs_title_subjectivity"        "abs_title_sentiment_polarity"  "TargetVarCont"                
[64] "TargetVar1"                    "TargetVar2"
```

## Factor Check is Factor the rest are numeric

```
output.var <- "TargetVar2"
vars.to.exclude <- c("Factor_Check","Cor_Check","Cor_Check4","Cor_Check2","TargetVar1", "TargetVarCont")
```

## Building the model based on 80% of the data

```
train<-mydata[(1:round(nrow(mydata)*(0.8))),] 

train<-train[,!(names(train) %in% vars.to.exclude)] 

Train<- Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(~.-1 , data=train)

xgb <- xgboost(data = Train[,!(names(Train) %in% output.var)], label = Train[,output.var],max.depth = 2, eta = 1, nthread = 2, nround = 2, objective = "binary:logistic")
```

Train

> Error: shinyjs: could not find the Shiny session object. This usually
>   happens when a shinyjs function is called from a context that wasn't
>   set up by a Shiny session.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: That doesn't seem like an error from `xgboost`... what does `traceback()` show after the error?

Comment: I think it is related to the R version.Please try it on 3.3.0 or higher.

Comment: Always, always, always, state the versions. What versions of R, xgboost and Matrix? I am currently seeing some weirdness with Matrix 1.2-4.

Comment: Hi @Basel.D, I know its long ago, but could you solve your problem? I happen to have the same question